# Publicly available list of asynchronous calls in android srouce?

Tags: android, asynchronous

I am working on a project that involves static analysis of Android source. Regarding this I need a list of all asynchronous calls in android source. Is there such a list available or can be obtained from somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Is there such a list available or can be obtained from somewhere?

No. There are tens of thousands of lists that would be needed, one for each device model and OS version that shipped for that device model, as the "Android source" is modified by device manufacturers.

Furthermore, the only way to try to come up with this list would be through static analysis of the source code, which means you should be capable of coming up with this list yourself, for whatever "Android source" you happen to be investigating.

Comment: Thanks. I believe the project uses the following Android source: http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html.